# InnerHTML does not include the "frame" tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a DOM element, which inside it has a node with the tag "frame".
But when I do innerHTML, the "frame" tag disappears. Why?

Example:

I have this string:

```
<div><p>Text</p><frame></frame></div>
```

If I want to put this string as the HTML of an element, the "frame" tag disappears:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str.trim();
```

Result:

```
<div><p>Text</p></div>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: If your page begins with `<!doctype type>` you are using HTML5. `<frame>` is not a valid element in HTML5, it's valid in HTML4.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `<frame>` inside `<body>` tag.
For that, write `<frameset>` instead of `<body>` and use `<frame>` inside `<frameset></frameset>`.
And, in the `<body>` tag( or DOM), you can use `<iframe>`.

Comment: But I'm creating a "frame" tag not by HTML logic, but rather because I want to create a custom html element, and I have to use the name "frame".

Comment: @Giest This is the right answer, see [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp) and [this demo](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_frame_cols), you see `<frameset>` replaces `<body>`

Comment: To customize your own tag, some more code is needed. see [this link](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var container = document.createElement('div');
var div = document.createElement('div');
var p=document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML="Text";
var frame=document.createElement('frame');
div.appendChild(p);
div.appendChild(frame);
container.appendChild(div);
alert(container.innerHTML);
document.getElementById("mainContainer").appendChild(container);
alert(document.getElementById("mainContainer").innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually create the `<frame>` on the page, it's just stored in the variable. Check your DevTools (F12), you won't be able to find it

Comment: I know, but you can append as well like that let me do that as well

Comment: Now check I have appended you can check using inspect element

Comment: I'll be damned!

Comment: If you got your answerthen please accept this answer :)

Comment: Wasn't my question ;)

Comment: ohhhhhhhh okay :)